# Can I show query output?

Tags: channel-entries

I'm having a difficult time trying to troubleshoot what is wrong with my page in expression engine.

I have a channel called site_pages and I'd like to select the entry for it, but it doesn't work... I'm almost sold on just using php for everything because Expression Engine is soooooooo ridiculous to troubleshoot these issues.

Here is what I'm running as a test; this h1 doesn't even render;

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="site_pages" url_title="new"}
<h1>Hello 1</h1>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What I'm really looking for is this;  But I'm not that advanced yet...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="site_pages" url_title="new"}
<img src="{page_banner}" alt="header image" class="img-responsive"/>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**EDIT:**

I got some data to show on the site by creating a new field that matches the url_title and can get data back by this

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="site_pages" pageId="new"}
<img src="{page_banner}" alt="header image" class="img-responsive"/>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Still odd, I can't easily output the query run by expression engine

Comment: I've gone through "Output and Debugging Preferences" and turned on everything just like EE says to, but I'm not getting anything still.  I wish there was an easy way for this to work...#nogood https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter [dynamic="no"](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic) to your first tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="site_pages" url_title="new" dynamic="no"}
    <h1>Hello 1</h1>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```